# Nested resources in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I'm dealing with a nested situation in xaml such that I have a toolbar in it as

```
<Expander x:Name="expander1" Header="Controls" 
          Content="{StaticResource FC}" IsExpanded="True" />
```

While static resource `FC` has been defined in another xaml file as  in FC.xaml as

```
<tb:Toolbox x:Key="FC" ItemSize="70,70" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

How can I use it in my code behind? please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the toolbox *FC* resource in your code behind. You could use the  [FrameworkElement.FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) using "FC" as key and casting the result to the Toolbox type.

If the resource FC is available to your windows/control it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using it like this -

```
Toolbox toolbox = expander1.Content as Toolbox;
```

This should work; in case you want to access it from Resource Dictionary(your xaml file) then use `FrameworkElement.FindResource` as Andrei suggested.